# How to disable MSN mobile? (mobile icon next to my name whenever I'm offline)

Tags: windows-live-messenger

Long-long time ago I somehow (I don't remember now) activated some MSN Messenger feature that allowed me to receive messages sent to me as an SMS while I was offline. Now **when I'm signed off, people see me as if i was signed on from a mobile phone**... there is mobile phone icon next to me.

I would like get rid of that. **Where can I disable this feature?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSN Messenger:

Options -> Phone

Check the settings there. Chances are that the "Allow people on my contact list to send messages to my mobile" box is checked. Uncheck it. You might also want to delete any phone numbers in the boxes above there too.

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.goodbye-microsoft.com.

Note: the above answer is a joke.  Do not do this unless you intend to replace Windows with gNewSense GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In all seriousness, you may find something useful at the [Windows Annoyances](http://www.annoyances.org/) website.